# Я не понимаю как настроить celery и rabbitmq на Windows

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

Сейчас покажу код, делаю на ubuntu все то же самое, что и на Windows
Windows код не исполняет, не отправляет email, с ubuntu этот же проект работает прекрасно.Как заставить работать celery на windows?
**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*********@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
```

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import task
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .models import Order

@task
def order_created(order_id):
    '''Задача отправки email-уведомлений при успешном оформлении заказа'''
    order = Order.objects.get(id = order_id)
    subject = 'Order nr. {}'.format(order.id)
    message = 'Dear {},\n\nYou have successfully placed an order.\
                You order id is {}'.format(order.first_name,order.id)
    mail_sent = send_mail(subject,message,'ferrarigto733@gmail.com',[order.email], fail_silently=False)

    return mail_sent

@task
def debug_task():
    print('Request :{0!r}'.format(1))
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myshop.settings')

app = Celery('myshop')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**views.py**

```
def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order = order,
                                         product = item['product'],
                                         price = item['price'],
                                         quantity = item['quantity'])
            cart.clear()
            #Запуск ассинхронной задачи  celery -A myshop worker -l info
            order_created.delay(order.id)
            #debug_task.delay()
            return render(request,'orders/order/created.html',{'order':order})
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
        return render(request,'orders/order/create.html',{'cart':cart,'form':form})
```

Вот сижу уже второй день и не могу разобраться, почему на Linux все гладко, а windows козни строит и не шлет мне e-mail. Он обиделся на меня или что я должен сделать, чтобы windows нормально сработал с celery и rabbitmq.
Следует отметить, что celery на Windows видит задачу, создает поток, но не возвращает success, просто вечно висисит в состоянии Recieved tasks.
В общем,для краткости поясню вопрос: Почему celery на windows не выполняет задачу, что я делаю не так, как исправить?

Comment: не совсем понимаю ваши настройки для брокера. в документации они выглядят как `transport://userid:password@hostname:port/virtual_host`

Comment: @5c0rp Куда их надо указать? Из любопытства спрошу, а почему линукс не требует этой настройки? Я сижу черезь гостя, мне на винде почему-то не позволено создать пользователя

Answer (score 0):

Как говорят, вечеринка уже кончилась, но может кому еще будет полезно.

Формат корректной команды запуска воркера в среде Windows следующий:

```
celery -A proj worker -l info --pool=solo
```

Т.е. + "`--pool=solo`".

Причину не знаю, увидел эту инфу в [англоязычном туториале](https://youtu.be/8lnybIaDz2M?t=368).
Прямым текстом говорится, что если этого не сделать, задачи будут висеть в стадии инициализации.

И да, можно (и, наверное, нужно) [создать для RabbitMQ юзера, дать ему права и создать хост](https://django.fun/docs/celery/ru/5.1/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/rabbitmq/#setting-up-rabbitmq).
А также не забыть в случае Windows предварительно установить Erlang.

Но это не изменит того факта, что без "--pool=solo" работать не будет.

Изучение вопроса было увлекательным.
Особенно с учетом [вот этого](https://django.fun/docs/celery/ru/5.1/faq/#does-celery-support-windows).
Это придало вопросу пикантности с самого старта.

P.S.
Настройки брокера прописываются в Django settings.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://myuser:mypassword@localhost:5672/myvhost'
```

или же в celery.py:

```
app = Celery('myshop', broker='amqp://myuser:mypassword@localhost:5672/myvhost')
```